# how to set up facebook sdk on PHP hosted on xampp on windows

Tags: php

I'm trying to setup the facebook marketing sdk in php but I cant seem to get past the first part since I dont know what this "terminal" is.

instructions can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/sdks/

I could get the composer via an alternative method. Either by getting the executable setup or by adding .php to the installer and running it via browser but the next step is

"//Then install it through composer:
php composer.phar install --no-dev"

I cant run the .phar file via accessing it in the browser. It also shows a few errors when I replace the .phar with .php and doing the same method previously by accessing it through the browser.

Basically two things I need to understand
 1. Where do I input those commands on a windows 7 OS
 2. Where do I place the files for the facebook marketing SDK? just under htdocs in xampp?

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows, then use the Command Prompt to run further commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Where do I input those commands on a windows 7 OS**

- Open the command line (https://www.howtogeek.com/254401/34-useful-keyboard-shortcuts-for-the-windows-command-prompt/)
- Go to your project folder and use those commands

**Where do I place the files for the facebook marketing SDK?**

Composer will make a directory (/vendor) within the folder that you currently are. Then composer will put the required files to the right place automatically.